# Can you use a subquery result as a conversion type?

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to find the datatype of a certain column and using that to convert a value that I am hardcoding (likely a 1 as that seems to be the most flexible) to the datatype of the column that it will be inserted into dynamically.  I'm running this SQL from C#, but Entity Framework and Stored Procedures are currently unavailable.  I just need to know whether I can use a subquery on the system tables (sys.types specifically) to dynamically choose which data type I'm converting to.

Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET ColumnName = 
COALESCE(
    (SELECT TOP(1) ColumnName
    FROM TableName
    Where TableName IS NOT NULL), 
    CAST(1 AS (SELECT t.name 
        FROM sys.types t 
        JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id 
        WHERE c.object_id = Object_id('dbo.TableName') AND 
        c.name = 'ColumnName')))
WHERE ColumnName IS NULL
```

What this is attempting to do is if there is already a value that is NOT NULL in the column, use that (as I'm just attempting to fill NULL's in the column with dummy data particular to that type) and to otherwise search for the type of that column and convert the value `1` to it.

Any insights?

Comment: You'd be better off using a CASE statement than what you're doing here with attempting to cast... and relying on implicit conversions.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql for this....but something is pretty strange here. Why do you always want to use a 1 regardless of the datatype? This value will work for many datatypes but not all of them. Things like uniqueidentifier will throw an exception because 1 is not valid. Other datatypes like datetime will give you a result but it is useless.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not looking for a useful result, just something to fill in the NULL values for whatever column I'm looking at, and they're all int, varchar, decimal, bigint: convertible from int. 
pmbAustin You're right I'll probably end up using a CASE statement; I was just wondering if there were any better ways to do it.

Comment: Filling in NULL with a placeholder like this is a bit strange. But just use '1', that will implicitly convert to those datatypes. But beware...if you have actual data with that value you will have no to know if the '1' you see is a result of your query populating placeholder values or the actual value. NULL is the appropriate value when there is no value. That is what NULL is for.

Comment: @SeanLange I realize it is strange, but rolling back migrations that alter a column to have NULLABE:false when it was NULLABLE:true fails when there are NULL values already in the column.

Comment: Possibly a better solution is to use an empty string instead of 1. SQL Server, for most data types, converts empty string to a "default value" e.g. '' -> INT -> 0; '' -> DATETIME -> 01-01-1900; '' -> BIT -> 0 etc. This, of course, is not true for all data types, especially newer ones such as geography, uniqueidentifier etc.

Comment: @Alex that sounds like a much better idea.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you to build Dinamic SQL as below:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TableName
SET ColumnName = 
COALESCE(
    (SELECT TOP(1) ColumnName
    FROM TableName
    Where TableName IS NOT NULL), 
    ' + 
        (SELECT t.name 
        FROM sys.types t 
        JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id 
        WHERE c.object_id = Object_id('TableName ') AND 
        c.name = 'ColumnName') + '))
WHERE ColumnName IS NULL;'
PRINT @SQL; -- For debugging purposes
EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL;
```

I have tried with a local table and it looks fine.